# Predual of $BMO(\mathbb{T}^d) $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In 1971, Fefferman characterized the predual of $BMO(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as the Hardy space $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Is there a characterization of the predual of $BMO(\mathbb{T}^d$)?

Comment: predual, not dual.

Comment: thank you I corrected this and the year of Fefferman's result.